# Is there a way for python to maintain variable state between successive runs?

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management

I am writing a code that seeks to combine 2 separate simulators. The first simulator provides a list of outputs that I write to a file, and the second simulator reads these as its input and generates another output that is fed back to the first simulator.

The second simulator is written in python and is converted to an executable file. So the first simulator calls the executable and the output of the executable is returned to the first simulator.

The problem that I am facing is that every time the first simulator calls the executable, it is like a fresh run due to which the previous state of the variables in my python code is lost. Is there a way to make the variables persist?

Comment: Have you looked into using `pickle` module to cache state?  You could toss all of your variables into dictionary and pickle it when done and retrieve when restarting...

Comment: @AirSquid Having the pickle solved the issue, and as pickle overwrites the previous value, it is safely working for me.